# Error: Kraken API returned error: Query: Unknown asset pair

Tags: api, zenbot

I'm trying to backfill a pair from kraken. But I get this error:

```
blade@debian:~/zenbot$ zenbot backfill kraken.XXBT-ZEUR --days 1node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises is deprecated.
    In the future, you will have to enable it yourself.
    See https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/319. module.js:635:30

    Trades error:
    Error: Kraken API returned error: Query:Unknown asset pair
        at Request._callback (/home/blade/zenbot/node_modules/kraken-api/kraken.js:155:34)
        at Request.self.callback (/home/blade/zenbot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/blade/zenbot/node_modules/request/request.js:1060:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/blade/zenbot/node_modules/request/request.js:980:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

    getTrades() returned no trades, --start may be too remotely in the past.
```

I've tried with gdax and it works. Where is the problem? zenbot or kraken?

When I see graphic on status.kraken.com, their API seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but take a look at [`products.json`](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/blob/unstable/extensions/exchanges/kraken/products.json). And try XBT/EUR as label. So `kraken.XBT-EUR`.